# WPF: rows and columns in an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I've tried putting children of both a `ListView` and an `ItemsControl` in rows and columns, by setting a grid with `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` as the `ItemsPanel` property.

However the child control always aligns to Row 1 and Column 1, when I put

```
<ItemsControl>

   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <!-- Grid with rows & columns ... -->
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" ... />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

How can I make this work? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried a `UniformGrid`?

Comment: Possibilities: (1) use a `UniformGrid`; (2) use a `WrapPanel` and use the `ItemTemplate` to make your item containers a fixed size; (3) write a custom panel.  Note that you'll lose virtualization support unless you find a third-party panel that supports virtualization (or write one yourself).

Comment: ItemsControl with rows and columns is called `DataGrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ´Grid´ in the ´ItemTemplate´ rather than the ´ItemPanel´.  See example here:  http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

---

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PersonCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
            new Person() { FirstName = "Richard", LastName = "Bryson" },
            new Person() { FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Gates" },
            new Person() { FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "Sandler" }
        };
        itemsControl.ItemsSource = PersonCollection;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. This is quite what I am looking for. How can I remove the TextBlocks and bind the controls to a collection now? Is that possible? Many thanks.

Comment: _"How can I remove the TextBlocks and bind the controls to a collection?"_ What do you mean?  Bind the collection to something other than `TextBlock` controls?  What kind of controls?

Comment: Exactly, that would be some custom controls. That is what I intentionally wanted, I just simplified my code in the question with TextBlocks instead of a binding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In that case you can just create a `UserControl` in whichever look and feel you want.  The `UserControl` inherits the `DataContext` (i.e. the `Person` object), and you can bind `TextBlock` controls or whatever else controls you use in the `UserControl` to the `Person` properties just like it's shown in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties of the container that wraps the root element of the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="iccc">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>cell 2:2...</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: THIS is what i've been searching for weeks now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if you don't know how many elements you'll have under your ItemsControl, ie. how many rows and columns should be rendered?