# Insert Labels with ItemsControl in Grid

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to sort Labels from an ItemsControl to my Grid.
When I bind the Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties, the position of the column and row is not effected.
What am I doing wrong?

[Labels have the wrong positions in the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWJUd.png)

Here my View.xaml

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="MainVM"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource MainVM}">

    <Grid Width="500">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding MachineList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border  BorderBrush="Black" Background="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2">

                        <Label Content="{Binding SerialNumber}"                    
                               Grid.Column="{Binding StationNumber}" 
                               Grid.Row="{Binding LineNumber}"
                               Margin="0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Background="LightBlue"
                               />

                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Here my MainViewModel.cs

```
   public class MainViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Machine> MachineList { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Machine m1 = new Machine(0, "Row1 Column3", 1, 3, MachineType.SX);
        Machine m2 = new Machine(0, "Row1 Column2", 1, 2, MachineType.SX);
        Machine m3 = new Machine(0, "Row2 Column1", 2, 1, MachineType.SX);
        MachineList = new ObservableCollection<Machine>();

        MachineList.Add(m1);
        MachineList.Add(m2);
        MachineList.Add(m3);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ItemsControl` displays the items in its own panel, which is no your grid so the grid property have no effect on the location of the items. The correct way to do this is to define your grid in the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` property like this:

```
<ItemsControl
            ItemsSource="{Binding MachineList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border  BorderBrush="Black" Background="Gainsboro"   BorderThickness="1" Margin="2">
                <Label Content="{Binding SerialNumber}" 
                                   Margin="0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Background="LightBlue"
                               />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid Width="500">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{binding ...}" />
            <Setter Property="Grig.Column" Value="{binding ...}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

see [here](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) in the  **The ItemsPanelTemplate property** section

Comment: I understand what problem you mean, but the modified xaml still doesn't work.
It now places all 3 labels in one cell

Comment: try to put the `ItemsControl` directly in the `StackPanel`

Comment: also, I just realized, you need to put `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` on the `Border` not the `Label`. I Edited the answer

Comment: Hmm... still don't works

It is now like this:

<StackPanel>
  Your XAML Code
</StackPanel>

EDIT:
Putting row/column on the border doesen't help

Comment: I googled some more and found the problem each `border` is surrounded by a `ContentPresenter`. you need to use `ItemContainerStyle` for that. edited again.

Comment: see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867702/10452752)