# Avalonia ItemsControl with Grid PanelTemplate and bound column & row indeces

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I try to use a grid as `ItemsPanelTemplate` in an `ItemsControl`. The column and row properties are bound. Unfortunately all items are overlapping and not displayed correctly.

My view:

```
<ItemsControl BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="{Binding YIndex}" Grid.Column="{Binding XIndex}" Padding="0" Background="White">
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="100" Background="{Binding Color}">
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Price}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

View model:

```
public class GridViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<GridItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new();
    public GridViewModel()
    {
        // dummy data
        for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (uint j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Items.Add(new GridItemViewModel()
                {
                    XIndex = i,
                    YIndex = j,
                    Name = $"X: {i} Y: {j}",
                    Price = 12.32m,
                    Color = "LightBlue"
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seems like the grid columns and rows are not set correctly. What am I missing?

If I just use a wrap panel as `PanelTemplate` without bound indices, it works fine, but I want to use explicitly a grid.

Comment: in WPF it is done like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833019/wpf-rows-and-columns-in-an-itemscontrol via ItemContainerStyle

Comment: I don't think this is what i am looking for. In addition I did not found ItemContainerStyle for Itemscontrol in Avalonia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of @ASh was a good start. Instead  of using the WPF *ItemContainerStyle*, the property setter can be used in Avalonia Grids as follows:

```
<ItemsControl.Styles>
    <Style x:DataType="md:Element" Selector="ItemsControl > ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Styles>
```

Based on the linked [blog entry](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/), I have created a respective behavior that allows the binding of the Grid.RowDefintions / Grid.ColumnDefintions for MVVM controls.

```
public static class GridDefinitionBehavior
{
    #region Public Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified number of Columns to ColumnDefinitions.
    /// Default Width is Auto
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly StyledProperty<int> ColumnCountProperty = AvaloniaProperty.Register<Grid, int>(
        name: "ColumnCount",
        defaultValue: -1);

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified number of Rows to RowDefinitions.
    /// Default Height is Auto
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly StyledProperty<int> RowCountProperty = AvaloniaProperty.Register<Grid, int>(
        name: "RowCount",
        defaultValue: -1);

    /// <summary>
    /// Makes the specified Column's Width equal to Star.
    /// Can set on multiple Columns
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly StyledProperty<string> StarColumnsProperty = AvaloniaProperty.Register<Grid, string>(
        name: "StarColumns",
        defaultValue: string.Empty);

    /// <summary>
    /// Makes the specified Row's Height equal to Star.
    /// Can set on multiple Rows
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly StyledProperty<string> StarRowsProperty = AvaloniaProperty.Register<Grid, string>(
        name: "StarRows",
        defaultValue: string.Empty);

    #endregion Public Fields

    #region Public Constructors

    static GridDefinitionBehavior()
    {
        ColumnCountProperty.Changed.Subscribe(e => ColumnCountChanged(
            obj: e.Sender,
            args: e));

        RowCountProperty.Changed.Subscribe(e => RowCountChanged(
            obj: e.Sender,
            args: e));

        StarColumnsProperty.Changed.Subscribe(e => StarColumnsChanged(
            obj: e.Sender,
            args: e));

        StarRowsProperty.Changed.Subscribe(e => StarRowsChanged(
            obj: e.Sender,
            args: e));
    }

    #endregion Public Constructors

    #region Public Methods

    public static void ColumnCountChanged(AvaloniaObject obj, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (obj is Grid grid
            && (int)args.NewValue >= 0)
        {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

            for (var index = 0; index < (int)args.NewValue; index++)
            {
                var definition = new ColumnDefinition()
                {
                    Width = GridLength.Auto
                };

                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(definition);
            }

            SetStarColumns(grid);
        }
    }

    public static int GetColumnCount(AvaloniaObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(ColumnCountProperty);
    }

    public static int GetRowCount(AvaloniaObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(RowCountProperty);
    }

    public static string GetStarColumns(AvaloniaObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(StarColumnsProperty);
    }

    public static string GetStarRows(AvaloniaObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(StarRowsProperty);
    }

    public static void RowCountChanged(AvaloniaObject obj, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (obj is Grid grid
            && (int)args.NewValue >= 0)
        {
            grid.RowDefinitions.Clear();

            for (var index = 0; index < (int)args.NewValue; index++)
            {
                var definition = new RowDefinition()
                {
                    Height = GridLength.Auto
                };

                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(definition);
            }

            SetStarRows(grid);
        }
    }

    public static void SetColumnCount(AvaloniaObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnCountProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetRowCount(AvaloniaObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RowCountProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetStarColumns(AvaloniaObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(StarColumnsProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetStarRows(AvaloniaObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(StarRowsProperty, value);
    }

    public static void StarColumnsChanged(AvaloniaObject obj, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (obj is Grid grid
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.NewValue.ToString()))
        {
            SetStarColumns(grid);
        }
    }

    public static void StarRowsChanged(AvaloniaObject obj, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (obj is Grid grid
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.NewValue.ToString()))
        {
            SetStarRows(grid);
        }
    }

    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Private Methods

    private static void SetStarColumns(Grid grid)
    {
        var starColumns = GetStarColumns(grid);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(starColumns))
        {
            var regex = new Regex(starColumns);

            for (int i = 0; i < grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(i.ToString()))
                {
                    grid.ColumnDefinitions[i].Width = new GridLength(
                        value: 1,
                        type: GridUnitType.Star);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SetStarRows(Grid grid)
    {
        var starRows = GetStarRows(grid);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(starRows))
        {
            var regex = new Regex(starRows);

            for (int i = 0; i < grid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(i.ToString()))
                {
                    grid.RowDefinitions[i].Height = new GridLength(
                        value: 1,
                        type: GridUnitType.Star);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

The respective repository can [be found here](https://github.com/budul100/AvaloniaGridDefinitionBehavoir).